# How to test a reactive method within Rest Controller called from service

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux, reactor

```
The following is my rest controller code 

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, value = "/myMethod")
        public Flux<Integer> myMethod() {       
            return service.myServiceMethod();
        }


My service method is   

      public Flux<Integer> myServiceMethod() {
                return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> no++).map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
            }

I am trying to write a test as below but it is not working

@Autowired
    NumberEventService serv; 

@Test
    public void test() {
      StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> 
            Flux.just(serv.generateNumberEvent()).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
            .expectSubscription() //t == 0  
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))   
            .expectNextCount(1) 
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .expectNextCount(1) 
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .expectNextCount(1) 
            .expectComplete()   
            .verify();
    }
```

I get an error as

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/TimedScheduler
    at reactor.test.StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(StepVerifier.java:167)
    at reactor.test.StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(StepVerifier.java:140)
```

I launched the app in the port 8080 and ran the test. What is the mistake I am doing?

I will launch this method in 8080 and a client in the port 8082 will consume the event.

How can this be unit tested?

Comment: a NCDFE suggests an issue with dependencies. Could you post your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will encounter a `NoClassDefFoundError` when `reactor-core` versions do not match between what spring-starter-reactor brings and the reactor-test addons.

You have to look at your `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependencies, and search the version of the `reactor-core` module.

Then you'll be able to add the correct version of the `reactor-test` module.

In my example, the current version of the `reactor-core` module is `3.1.8.RELEASE`, so I have to add the same version of the `reactor-test` module.

You can check the maven repository of the reactor test support [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-test)

[image]